# How to decode this representation of a unicode string in Python?

Tags: python, utf-8, gmail-imap

I'm using `imaplib` to fetch subjects of email messages from Gmail, and some of the subjects look like this:

```
=?utf-8?Q?12_=D7=A1=D7=91=D7=99=D7=97?=
```

How can I decode this representation into a normal Unicode text?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your string is encoded using the [Quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) format for MIME headers. The [`email.header` module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html) handles this for you:

```
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> for part in decode_header('=?utf-8?Q?12_=D7=A1=D7=91=D7=99=D7=97?='):
...     print(str(*part))
12 סביח
```

Comment: OMG THANKS! I've been looking for this answer for the past month. EXCELLENT! thanks